# How to order by when creating a new group in Linq code?

Tags: linq

I'm new to Linq, so I'm struggling to get my code right. I am using LinqPad 5, using C#, connected to an Oracle database.

I need to display the total number of books by each publisher from a table, and order them by publisher ID. The order by part is where I'm stuck, as I can get it to output the count correctly, but I can't get it ordered correctly.

Here is the table I'm using (some irrelevant columns are omitted).

```
    BOOK_ISBN    BOOK_TITLE                   BOOK_PUBID
    6541546      Birds and their cousins      4
    3214996      Outer worlds                 2
    3313545      Cats, Cats, Cats             3
    ...
```

I've tried multiple ways of writing this, and placing 'order by' in different places. I realise that putting the 'order by' before the group means that it's basically irrelevant, and makes no difference. I have tried putting the order by inside the select new area but it keeps throwing up errors and I can't get it to work.

This is the first way I tried, as a C# expression.

```
from b in Books
.OrderByDescending(b => b.BookPubid)
group b.BookTitle by b.BookPubid into BooksbyPublisher 
select new

{
PublisherId     = BooksbyPublisher.Key,
Numberofbooks   = BooksbyPublisher.Count()
}
```

This is the second way I tried it, as a C# statement.

```
var myQuery =
from b in Books
.OrderByDescending(b => b.BookPubid)
group b.BookTitle by b.BookPubid into BooksbyPublisher 
select new

{
PublisherId     = BooksbyPublisher.Key,
Numberofbooks   = BooksbyPublisher.Count(),
};

myQuery.Dump();
```

I expect the output to be:

```
PublisherId     Numberofbooks
1               2
2               2
3               3
4               4
5               3
```

But it comes out as:

```
PublisherId     Numberofbooks

1               2 
2               2 
4               4 
5               3 
3               3
```

Comment: why are you using BookTitle as publisher id.. it may give you an incorrect result.

Comment: So that it groups the books by the publishers Id. If I group it by Book title, it just displays all the book titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a sequence of `Books`, and you want to group these `Books` into groups of `Books` that are published by the same publisher (= has same `PublisherId`). From every group of `Books` you want to select several properties.

You are right, for this you'll use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__)

```
IQueryable<Book> books = ...  // your input collection of books
var result = books.GroupBy(book => book.PublisherId,   // make groups of books with same PublisherId

    // parameter ResultSelector: from every publisherId, and all books that have this
    // publisherId make one object:
    (publisherId, booksWithThisPublisherId) => new
    {
         // Select the properties you want,
         // in your example you want the PublisherId and the number of books of this Publisher
         PublisherId = publisherId,
         NumberOfBooks = booksWithThisPublisherId.Count(),
    })

    // and you want to sort them with ascending publisherId:
    .OrderBy(publisherWithNrOfBooks => publisherWithNumberOfBooks.PublisherId);
```

In words:

Take your input collection of Books. Make groups of Books with the same PublisherId. From every Group, make one new object. This object contains the common PublisherId that all books in this group have. Also count the number of books in this Group.

Finally, take each "publisher with his number of books" and order them by ascending PublisherId.

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Got it running perfectly!